# Какова структура этой функции: student(char *pname="no name"):name(pName)?

Tags: c++, функции

student-имя. В скобках один аргумент - указатель на тип char с начальным значением "no name" (но и здесь я не уверен). А что такое :name(pName) ?!

Comment: Это ф-ция член класса? Давайте код класса тогда...

Answer (score 6):

Подозреваю, что student - это класс, и то, что вы пишете - это конструктор. Тогда name - это одно из полей. name(pName)  - это инициализация этого поля.

Comment: Угу. Такие же мысли.